# Replace characters before a string match in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace space/tab/or any character before a string match is found.

Given this input:

**"1)apple. 2)blue pen. 3)black shirt. 4)red hat."**

I want this output:

**1)apple._2)blue pen._3)black shirt._4)red hat.**

There is a fixed pattern, such as a digit followed by `)`, and before that I want a replacement.

Code:

```
$str = "1)apple. 2)blue pen. 3)black shirt. 4)red hat.";
print "before ==> $str \n";
$str =~ s/.(\d+)/_/g;
print "after ==> $str \n"; # o/p: 1)apple._)blue pen._)black shirt._)red hat.
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to replace any character preceding the digit(s) or whatever your fixed pattern is, or do you only want to replace it if it's a space? For example, should `1)apple2)blue pen.` become `1)appl_2)blue pen.`, or `1)apple_2)blue pen.`, or fail to match the pattern altogether (no change)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your pattern `s/.(\d+)/_/g` to `s/.(\d+\))/_\1/g`. the `\1` in the pattern means the value you capture

update:

After turning on warnings, it suggests that it's better written `\1` to `$1`

Comment: In the replacement string, you should should `$1`, not `\1`. The latter is a back-reference, for use in pattern definition. If you enable warnings, as you should, you'll see this.

Comment: thank you for pointing out that and I have seen the warning. @FMc

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the captured match `$1` to the replacement side of your substitution operator.

```
$str =~ s/.(\d+\))/_$1/g;
```

You could also use a lookahead assertion here.

```
$str =~ s/.(?=\d+\))/_/g;
```

If you have a pattern with multiple digits, e.g `9)orange. 10)black shirt.` the above will **fail**. Instead you can use a negated match, which will do the trick.

```
$str =~ s/[^\d](?=\d+\))/_/g;
```